# Parse Cloud Hosting with Express and Handlebars Templates

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, handlebars.js

There is a node package for using handlebars templates in Express.js, express-handlebars, but I'd like to be able to use the same package in a Parse Cloud Hosting project. The only discussion I can find about how to make it work is here, and it's painfully brief: https://parse.com/questions/dynamic-website-handlebars-for-template-engine

The last comment mentions specifying the 'cloud' directory 'to the required command for a lot of dependent modules'. The author does not explain how he did that, and the thread is now closed.

After following the install instructions I have this in my main app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');

var home = require('cloud/routes/home');
var register = require('cloud/routes/register');
var login = require('cloud/routes/login');

var app = express();

// Configure the app
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'layouts/main.hbs'
}));

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('ABCDEFG1234567'));
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({ cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 }}));
app.use(app.router);

// Define all the endpoints
app.get('/', home.index);
app.get('/register', register.new);
app.post('/register', register.create);
app.get('/login', login.new);
app.post('/login', login.create);
app.get('/logout', login.destroy);

app.listen();
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
cloud
  └──routes
  └──views
      └──layouts
          └──main.hbs
      └──home
          └──index.hbs
      └──register
          └──new.hbs
      └──login
          └──new.hbs
config
node_modules
public
package.json
```

All route files are a slight variation of this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('home/index');
};
```

Running my app results in the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "home/index"
```

With the default 'ejs' templates, the app runs fine. Personally, I'm fine with ejs templates, but it's not up to me. Handlebars are what's required of the project, so that's what I'm out to accomplish. Thanks!